# Configure touchscreen on Debian?

Tags: debian, touch-screen

I have got Samsung Q1 Ultra with **Debian Squeeze** on it. Everything works okay, except **touchscreen**.

The arrow almost does not respond to touching -- it only moves once in a while to a random place after the screen being touched.

I have tried to calibrate the screen using `xinput-calibrate`, but it did not do anything, as the arrow did not respond to touching.

X11 generates configuration on start up, so I don't have Xorg.conf to append, but I have [**/user/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf**](http://pastebin.com/1y6mTGXb).

Should I try a different driver (if there are others)? Or is there some configuration that needs to be done? Or what might be wrong?

Comment: It happens the same on Whezze?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/TabletAndTouchScreen), Debian support for touchscreen is incomplete/under development.
You need to play a lot, and upgrade your Debian at least to wheezy (or maybe jessie).

Answer (score 3):

I have already done this for Debian 9. For more information just open my blog [link.](https://vakhokor.blogspot.com/2017/10/debian-9-touch-screen-calibration.html)

For touch screen we can use **libinput** or **evdev** driver. Libinput replaces the evdev driver. The configuration below is created for **evdev**.

Get information about **xserver-xorg-input**. The result there should not be **evdev** configuration file.

```
dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-input
```

Now install evdev driver.

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

Check if **evdev** driver is installed

```
dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-input
```

Check if configuration files are in **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d** directory.

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
ls
```

Result:

```
10-amdgpu.conf 10-evdev.conf 10-quirks.conf 40-libinput.conf 70-wacom.conf
```

We can **remove** libinput driver:

```
apt-get remove --auto-remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

Install **xinput-calibrator**

```
sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator
```

Check if you need to **swap axes**. if you need to swap just run:

```
xinit set-int-prop "eGalax Inc." "Evdev Axes Swap" 8 1
```

Run calibrator to get **correct x,y** positions.

```
xinput_calibrator --output-type xinput
```

Comment: The command you provided removes Cinnamon and Xfce desktops, and even the task-desktop package